# Ruby rubocop: how to freeze an array constant generated with splat

Tags: ruby, constants, freeze, rubocop, splat

I'm assigning an array constant like this:

```
NUMS = *(2..9)
```

Rubocop says

C: Freeze mutable objects assigned to constants.
NUMS = *(2..9)
               ^^^^^

---

So I try

```
NUMS = *(2..9).freeze
```

Rubocop says

C: Freeze mutable objects assigned to constants.
NUMS = *(2..9).freeze
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^

---

Tried

```
NUMS = (*(2..9)).freeze
```

Rubocop says

E: unexpected token tRPAREN
(Using Ruby 2.0 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)

NUMS = (*(2..9)).freeze
                         ^

---

Tried

```
NUMS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].freeze
```

Rubocop says

== happy_robot_dance (no errors)

I say

My hand hurts from typing 1, 2, 3, ... 9

Is there some way to use the splat to assign and freeze a constant?

Comment: `(2..9).to_a`, should be the same as `[2,3,4, ...etc]`. Wondering if the fact that `2..9` is a `Range` causes the issue. Regardless, if the original code works, then it seems like Rubocop's warning is unwarranted.

Comment: I agree that there is no reason to use splat for array coercion, when `#to_a` is available and much clearer. At the same time, this cop shouldn't have an opinion on that.

Answer (score 6):

This case was previously unaccounted for by RuboCop (read bug.)

I have added an [issue](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/3366) and a [pull request](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/pull/3367) that will fix this.

Meanwhile you can silence the cop by disabling it for this case using:

```
# rubocop:disable Style/MutableConstant
NUMS = *(2..9)
# rubocop:enable Style/MutableConstant
```

Or you can use `#to_a`:

```
NUMS = (2..9).to_a.freeze
```

Comment: NUMS = (2..9).to_a.freeze looks like the best solution for clarity and rubocop.  ty sir

Comment: If you want brevity, `NUMS = [*2..9].freeze` is equivalent to the latter solution in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

`NUMS = Array[*2..9].freeze`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case of appeasing Rubocop for its own sake - case 2 looks like it should work and therefore could be considered a bug. However, does this work?

```
why_do_i_exist = *(2..9)
NUMS = why_do_i_exist.freeze
```

Comment: Yes, this works.  But I still don't know why_i_exists ... ;-)