# Ruby Rubocop. MutableConstant - not detecting freeze

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I wrote a lib/animal.rb with several lists of params, and I want to reference that list in my controller and add it my params list. I did this because I use this list in several locations and didn't want to litter my code with a bunch of references to the library.

**Controller**

```
ANIMAL_TYPE_INPUT_PARAMS = *Animals::ANIMAL_TYPE_PARAMS.freeze

....

def familar_params
  params.permit(ANIMAL_TYPE_INPUT_PARAMS, OTHER_PARAM_LIST....)
end
```

**Lib/animal.rb**

```
module Animal

  # param lists
  ANIMAL_TYPE_PARAMS = [
    :animal_has_fur, :animal_id, :animal_weight
  ].freeze
end
```

Functionally it works just fine, but I am seeing a weird rubocop error. I would prefer to not disable MutableConstant for this section (disabling rubocop is usually a band aid that you pay for at some point).

**Rubocop error**

```
app/controllers/api/v1/example_controller.rb:55:24: C: Freeze mutable objects assigned to constants.
  ANIMAL_TYPE_INPUT_PARAMS = *Animals::ANIMAL_TYPE_PARAMS.freeze
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I looked into this question: [Ruby rubocop: how to freeze an array constant generated with splat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757237/ruby-rubocop-how-to-freeze-an-array-constant-generated-with-splat) But mine are already arrays, so I feel like it doesn't apply to me / shouldn't have to call to_a.

Comment: You don't need to freeze a constant, since it should... well, be constant.  Remove the `.freeze` from `Animals::ANIMAL_TYPE_PARAMS` and keep it on the array in `lib/animal.rb` and you'll be fine.

Comment: @binarymason My apologies. I had a huge typo! I am splatting the array. to the new params list

Comment: Why cant you ANIMAL_TYPE_INPUT_PARAMS = Animals::ANIMAL_TYPE_PARAMS

Comment: I get the same error of: Freeze mutable objects assigned to constants. If I do not splat it.  And I need to splat it so that it can be in the params list.

Comment: Whoops. Thought I had fixed this in a previous PR. Looks like there might be more edge cases. I will have a look at this once I have some free time. :-)

Comment: @alex_milhouse: Which version of RuboCop are you using? I can not reproduce this in `0.46.0` using the code you provided.

Comment: @Drenmi I am on version .0.42.0 . I will try upgrading and report back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @drenmi suggested, it was an older version of rubocop giving me this error. Once I upgraded to 0.46.0 the error was no longer.